Superimpose video over the detected image surface (Android only)
I would like to superimpose video on the detected target image. Currently it works for 3d model or 3d shapes. But I would like to use Video and display on exact same vertices where image was detected and that too through Android native only.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

this tutorial is slightly old but you might still get the gist of how to do it in Unity https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PyBDJvs0y1Q doing the same on a Native (Android only app) is probably quite harder.

Yeah, I am more looking for Android Native first and if that works then iOS Swift. Thanks

I am not aware of sample code for this but you might want to look into Opengl ES and do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823341/use-opengl-es-to-render-video-to-surfaceview-but-concerned-about-more-overhead
