# Android Media Muxer Not Working [Android/Java]

Tags: java, android, mediamuxer

## Media Muxer

**`Media Muxer`** Not Working In **Lolipop**

Testing on Android Emulator Api 22 (Lolipop)

here is my code for muxing audio and video file

```
public void muxer(File videoFile, File audioFile, long dowloadId) {
    String outputFile = "";
    String TAG = "MURGE";


    publishProgress(0, 0, dowloadId, 0, "Parsing");

    try {

        if (!new File(DataStore.getInstance(this).getPathDownload() + "/Final").exists()) {
            new File(DataStore.getInstance(this).getPathDownload() + "/Final").mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(DataStore.getInstance(this).getPathDownload() + "/Final/" + filename);
        file.createNewFile();

        outputFile = file.getAbsolutePath();

        if (videoFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Video File Present");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Video File Not Present");
        }
        if (audioFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Audio File Present");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Audio File Not Present");
        }

        MediaExtractor videoExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
        videoExtractor.setDataSource(videoFile.getPath());

        MediaExtractor audioExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
        audioExtractor.setDataSource(audioFile.getPath());

        Log.d(TAG, "Video Extractor Track Count " + videoExtractor.getTrackCount());
        Log.d(TAG, "Audio Extractor Track Count " + audioExtractor.getTrackCount());

        MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFile, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

        videoExtractor.selectTrack(0);
        MediaFormat videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
        int videoTrack = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat);

        audioExtractor.selectTrack(0);
        MediaFormat audioFormat = audioExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
        int audioTrack = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat);

        Log.d(TAG, "Video Format " + videoFormat.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "Audio Format " + audioFormat.toString());

        boolean sawEOS = false;
        int frameCount = 0;
        int offset = 100;
        int sampleSize = 1024 * 1024;
        ByteBuffer videoBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
        ByteBuffer audioBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo videoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo audioBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();


        videoExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
        audioExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);

        muxer.start();

        while (!sawEOS) {
            videoBufferInfo.offset = offset;
            videoBufferInfo.size = videoExtractor.readSampleData(videoBuf, offset);


            if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
                sawEOS = true;
                videoBufferInfo.size = 0;

            } else {
                videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = videoExtractor.getSampleTime();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    videoBufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME;
                } else {
                    videoBufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_SYNC_FRAME;
                }
                muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrack, videoBuf, videoBufferInfo);
                videoExtractor.advance();

                frameCount++;
                Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
                Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

            }
        }
        publishProgress(50, 0, 0, 0, "Parsing");
        Log.e(TAG, "frame:" + frameCount);


        boolean sawEOS2 = false;
        int frameCount2 = 0;
        while (!sawEOS2) {
            frameCount2++;

            audioBufferInfo.offset = offset;
            audioBufferInfo.size = audioExtractor.readSampleData(audioBuf, offset);

            if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
                sawEOS2 = true;
                audioBufferInfo.size = 0;
            } else {
                audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = audioExtractor.getSampleTime();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    videoBufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME;
                } else {
                    videoBufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_SYNC_FRAME;
                }
                muxer.writeSampleData(audioTrack, audioBuf, audioBufferInfo);
                audioExtractor.advance();


                Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
                Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

            }


        }
        publishProgress(100, 0, 0, 0, "Parsing");
        Log.e(TAG, "frame:" + frameCount2);

        muxer.stop();
        muxer.release();

        videoFile.delete();
        audioFile.delete();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Mixer Error 1 " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Mixer Error 2 " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**`Log cat`**

```
    02-19 17:15:11.292 5012-5207/packagename D/MURGE: Video Extractor Track Count 1
    02-19 17:15:11.292 5012-5207/packagename D/MURGE: Audio Extractor Track Count 1
    02-19 17:15:11.301 5012-5207/packagename D/MURGE: Video Format {height=720, width=1280, csd-1=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=8,capacity=8], max-input-size=691200, mime=video/avc, durationUs=209040000, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=32,capacity=32]}
    02-19 17:15:11.301 5012-5207/packagename D/MURGE: Audio Format {max-input-size=3110400, aac-profile=2, mime=audio/mp4a-latm, durationUs=209095691, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=2,capacity=2], channel-count=2, sample-rate=44100}
    02-19 17:15:11.318 5012-5207/packagename I/MPEG4Writer: limits: 4294967295/0 bytes/us, bit rate: -1 bps and the estimated moov size 3072 bytes
    02-19 17:15:11.320 5012-5207/packagename D/MURGE: Frame (1) Video PresentationTimeUs:40000 Flags:1 Size(KB) 1
    02-19 17:15:11.320 5012-5207/packagename D/MURGE: Frame (1) Audio PresentationTimeUs:0 Flags:0 Size(KB) 0
    02-19 17:15:11.322 5012-5225/packagename I/MPEG4Writer: setStartTimestampUs: 40000
    02-19 17:15:11.322 5012-5225/packagename I/MPEG4Writer: Earliest track starting time: 40000
    02-19 17:15:11.323 5012-5207/packagename D/MURGE: Frame (2) Video PresentationTimeUs:160000 Flags:1 Size(KB) 0
    02-19 17:15:11.323 5012-5207/packagename D/MURGE: Frame (2) Audio PresentationTimeUs:0 Flags:0 Size(KB) 0
    02-19 17:15:11.325 5012-5207/packagename D/MURGE: Frame (3) Video PresentationTimeUs:80000 Flags:1 Size(KB) 0
    02-19 17:15:11.325 5012-5207/packagename D/MURGE: Frame (3) Audio PresentationTimeUs:0 Flags:0 Size(KB) 0
    02-19 17:15:11.326 5012-5225/packagename E/MPEG4Writer: timestampUs 40000 < lastTimestampUs 120000 for Video track
    02-19 17:15:11.394 5012-5025/packagename I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 22027(1475KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 17% free, 6MB/8MB, paused 14.223ms total 92.193ms
    02-19 17:15:38.534 5012-5025/packagename I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1599(1338KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 17% free, 6MB/8MB, paused 6.730ms total 24.344ms
    02-19 17:16:00.019 1759-1814/system_process I/ProcessStatsService: Prepared write state in 1ms
    02-19 17:16:16.766 1156-1565/? I/AudioFlinger: BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4096) from active list on thread 0xb58ac000
    02-19 17:16:22.314 2659-3143/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Called cancelTask for already completed task com.google.android.gms/.chimera.container.ConfigService{u=0 tag="ChimeraConfigService_OneOffRetry" trigger=window{start=3300s,end=3900s,earliest=-292s,latest=307s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED] scheduled=-3592s last_run=-245s jid=N/A status=ACTIVE retries=0 client_lib=MANCHEGO_GCM-13280000} :TIMED_OUT
    02-19 17:16:26.214 5012-5012/packagename E/WV: URL :: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IssysxAisfo
    02-19 17:16:26.267 1759-2555/system_process I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2b9bc651com.android.org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerListener@3b664eb6
    02-19 17:16:27.457 1759-3533/system_process I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2b9bc651com.android.org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerListener@16d77914 req=3flags=0x0
    02-19 17:16:27.469 5012-5235/packagename I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
    02-19 17:16:27.483 5012-5236/packagename I/SoftAAC2: limiting to stereo output
    02-19 17:16:27.487 5012-5236/packagename I/SoftAAC2: Reconfiguring decoder: 0->44100 Hz, 0->2 channels
    02-19 17:16:27.488 5012-5240/packagename I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
    02-19 17:16:27.525 5012-5240/packagename W/OMXNodeInstance: [1:google.vp9.decoder] component does not support metadata mode; using fallback
    02-19 17:16:27.525 5012-5240/packagename E/ACodec: [OMX.google.vp9.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -1010
    02-19 17:16:27.525 5012-5240/packagename E/OMXNodeInstance: getParameter(1:google.vp9.decoder, ParamVideoAndroidVp8Encoder(0x6f600007)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
    02-19 17:16:27.541 1143-1196/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 462848
    02-19 17:16:27.566 1143-2252/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 462848
    02-19 17:16:33.209 5012-5012/packagename E/Service: E/MPEG4Writer: timestampUs 40000 < lastTimestampUs 120000 for Video track
    02-19 17:16:33.324 5012-5012/packagename E/Service: E/MPEG4Writer: timestampUs 40000 < lastTimestampUs 120000 for Video track
    02-19 17:16:33.571 5012-5012/packagename E/Service: E/MPEG4Writer: timestampUs 40000 < lastTimestampUs 120000 for Video track
    02-19 17:16:53.291 1759-1813/system_process I/UsageStatsService: User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
    02-19 17:17:18.407 5012-5025/packagename I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1371(1112KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 7MB/8MB, paused 5.788ms total 12.171ms
    02-19 17:17:59.364 5012-5012/packagename E/Service: lastTimestampUs
    02-19 17:18:46.471 5012-5012/packagename E/Service: timestampUs
    02-19 17:19:13.298 5012-5012/packagename E/Service: timestampUs
    02-19 17:19:13.940 1156-1565/? I/AudioFlinger: BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4096) from active list on thread 0xb58ac000
    02-19 17:19:17.531 5012-5012/packagename E/Service: MPEG4Writer
    02-19 17:19:23.377 5012-5012/packagename E/WV: URL :: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dZ0fwJojhrs
    02-19 17:19:23.431 1759-2555/system_process I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2b9bc651com.android.org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerListener@16d77914
    02-19 17:19:24.428 1759-1805/system_process I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2b9bc651com.android.org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerListener@17bac7b2 req=3flags=0x0
    02-19 17:19:24.433 5012-5247/packagename I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
    02-19 17:19:24.449 5012-5248/packagename I/SoftAAC2: limiting to stereo output
    02-19 17:19:24.449 5012-5248/packagename I/SoftAAC2: Reconfiguring decoder: 0->44100 Hz, 0->2 channels
    02-19 17:19:24.454 5012-5252/packagename I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
    02-19 17:19:24.458 5012-5252/packagename W/OMXNodeInstance: [1:google.vp9.decoder] component does not support metadata mode; using fallback
    02-19 17:19:24.458 5012-5252/packagename E/ACodec: [OMX.google.vp9.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -1010
    02-19 17:19:24.458 5012-5252/packagename E/OMXNodeInstance: getParameter(1:google.vp9.decoder, ParamVideoAndroidVp8Encoder(0x6f600007)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
    02-19 17:19:24.484 1143-1190/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 462848
    02-19 17:19:24.554 1143-3796/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 462848
    02-19 17:19:43.077 5012-5025/packagename I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 858(693KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 7MB/8MB, paused 9.216ms total 21.841ms
    02-19 17:19:46.978 5012-5012/packagename E/Service: lastTimestampUs
    02-19 17:20:04.939 5012-5025/packagename I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 705(591KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 8% free, 7MB/8MB, paused 7.366ms total 18.008ms
    02-19 17:20:26.415 5012-5025/packagename I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 592(479KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 7MB/8MB, paused 6.232ms total 15.288ms
    02-19 17:20:46.467 5012-5025/packagename I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 409(344KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 7MB/8MB, paused 5.358ms total 10.100ms
    02-19 17:20:49.359 5012-5025/packagename I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 387(320KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 7MB/8MB, paused 9.664ms total 33.219ms
    02-19 17:21:51.433 5012-5012/packagename E/Service: Muxing Single Video/Audio Track
    02-19 17:22:45.690 5012-5012/packagename E/Service: MediaMuxer
    02-19 17:23:19.857 1156-1565/? I/AudioFlinger: BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4096) from active list on thread 0xb58ac000
    02-19 17:23:29.771 5012-5012/packagename E/WV: URL :: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pnMQLrS5sTE
    02-19 17:23:29.825 1759-2592/system_process I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2b9bc651com.android.org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerListener@17bac7b2
    02-19 17:23:31.800 1759-2618/system_process I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2b9bc651com.android.org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerListener@2e3d1280 req=3flags=0x0
    02-19 17:23:31.808 5012-5262/packagename I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
    02-19 17:23:31.843 5012-5263/packagename I/SoftAAC2: limiting to stereo output
    02-19 17:23:31.844 5012-5263/packagename I/SoftAAC2: Reconfiguring decoder: 0->44100 Hz, 0->2 channels
    02-19 17:23:31.850 5012-5267/packagename I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
    02-19 17:23:31.858 5012-5267/packagename W/OMXNodeInstance: [1:google.vp9.decoder] component does not support metadata mode; using fallback
    02-19 17:23:31.858 5012-5267/packagename E/ACodec: [OMX.google.vp9.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -1010
    02-19 17:23:31.859 5012-5267/packagename E/OMXNodeInstance: getParameter(1:google.vp9.decoder, ParamVideoAndroidVp8Encoder(0x6f600007)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
    02-19 17:23:31.875 1143-3796/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 462848
    02-19 17:23:31.892 1143-1818/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 462848
    02-19 17:23:41.652 5012-5025/packagename I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2063(1675KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 6MB/8MB, paused 5.382ms total 15.473ms
    02-19 17:24:12.950 1759-3533/system_process I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2b9bc651com.android.org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerListener@2e3d1280
    02-19 17:24:13.276 1759-2592/system_process I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2b9bc651com.android.org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerListener@3d09acfe req=3flags=0x0
    02-19 17:24:13.294 5012-5272/packagename I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
    02-19 17:24:13.308 5012-5273/packagename I/SoftAAC2: limiting to stereo output
    02-19 17:24:13.310 5012-5273/packagename I/SoftAAC2: Reconfiguring decoder: 0->44100 Hz, 0->2 channels
    02-19 17:24:13.312 5012-5277/packagename I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
    02-19 17:24:13.319 5012-5277/packagename W/OMXNodeInstance: [1:google.vp9.decoder] component does not support metadata mode; using fallback
    02-19 17:24:13.319 5012-5277/packagename E/ACodec: [OMX.google.vp9.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -1010
    02-19 17:24:13.319 5012-5277/packagename E/OMXNodeInstance: getParameter(1:google.vp9.decoder, ParamVideoAndroidVp8Encoder(0x6f600007)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
    02-19 17:24:13.342 1143-1190/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 462848
    02-19 17:24:13.377 1143-3796/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 462848
    02-19 17:24:53.642 2372-2372/com.android.systemui D/PhoneStatusBar: disable: < expand ICONS* alerts SYSTEM_INFO* back home recent clock search >
    02-19 17:24:54.628 2372-2372/com.android.systemui D/PhoneStatusBar: disable: < expand icons* alerts system_info* back home recent clock search >
    02-19 17:24:54.787 1759-2703/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@d13dc35 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@2cf788e6
    02-19 17:25:37.031 5012-5025/packagename I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1736(1453KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 6MB/8MB, paused 7.965ms total 16.716ms
```

I cant find where i am doing wrong its works on **`8.1.0`**

last log msg is

```
    02-19 17:15:11.325 5012-5207/packagename D/MURGE: Frame (3) Video PresentationTimeUs:80000 Flags:1 Size(KB) 0
    02-19 17:15:11.325 5012-5207/packagename D/MURGE: Frame (3) Audio PresentationTimeUs:0 Flags:0 Size(KB) 0
```

then

```
    02-19 17:15:11.326 5012-5225/packagename E/MPEG4Writer: timestampUs 40000 < lastTimestampUs 120000 for Video track
```

I dont know what is `timestampUs 40000 < lastTimestampUs 120000 for Video track` any one help please

> ## This is working in
>
> 1. Api 25 (**`Nougat`**) Emulator
> 2. Api 27 (**`Oreo`**) Emulator and Real Device
> 3. Api 28 (**`Pie`**) Emulator

Answer (score 0):

Try to refactor your extracting logic to using `videoExtractor.advance();` as a condition of `sawEOS`

```
      do {
            videoBufferInfo.offset = offset;
            videoBufferInfo.size = videoExtractor.readSampleData(videoBuf, offset);


            videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = videoExtractor.getSampleTime();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                videoBufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME;
            } else {
                videoBufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_SYNC_FRAME;
            }
            muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrack, videoBuf, videoBufferInfo);

         } while (videoExtractor.advance());
```

Comment: same massage E/MPEG4Writer: timestampUs 40000 < lastTimestampUs 80000 for Video track

Comment: replaced my while loop with your do while loop but same message

Comment: Try to change videoBufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_SYNC_FRAME; to videoBufferInfo.flags = extractor.getSampleFlags()

Comment: Also mixed file it should be always a new file, if you will try to write to an existing media file you should get an error

Comment: same log message its going in infinite loop